# How to reroute the output to a file with timestamp?

Tags: c++, linux

I have a c++ program in Linux (binary file, I cannot modify), which prints the messages it got from other programs, in the standard output.So, if I run the program, it will print messages time to time in standard output. I normally reroute to the output to a log file to read. 
`program > & 1.log`

sample 1.log file:

`message 1
message 2
message 3`

The problem is, the messages do not have the time stamp. So, I need to print the messages in `1.log` with received time.

Wanted form:

`07:12:08 211030 Message1
07:12:08 234630 Message1
07:12:08 254320 Message1`

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there could be some issues with the program not flushing output often, so timestamps might be later than the logging code ran, but you can easily write a filter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while (getline(std::cin, line))
    {
         time_t seconds = time(NULL);
         struct tm datetime = *localtime(&seconds);
         std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << datetime.tm_hour << ':'
                   << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << datetime.tm_min << ':'
                   << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << datetime.tm_sec << ' '
                   << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Then, if you compile that to say `timestamper`, invoke your program like this:

```
program | timestamper >& 1.log
```

Alternatively, use `awk`:

```
program | awk '{ print strftime("%T"), $0 }' >& 1.log
```

Comment: "setf" is not compiling for me. `setf is not a member of std` can you please correct it once?

Comment: Sorry - should be `setfill`... will fix.  Need the `<iomanip>` header for those too.  You can learn about them [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill)

Comment: `timestamper` is working perfectly... Thanks a lot! But the "awk" method is not working for me. May be some syntax errors.

Comment: `strftime` is a gawk extension. You would have to use gawk rather than awk for that to work.

Comment: @harmic: yes, on linux `awk` is normally a link to `gawk` though - it works for me fine on the Red Hat host here.  Definitely worth trying `gawk` explicitly though.

Comment: @Nadaraj: what specific errors are you seeing?  (Make sure you put single right quotes around the braces, not left quotes... you should be able to just cut and paste from this page to a linux shell prompt - works for me)

Comment: @Tony D I have tried the following program: `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
while(true)
{
cout<<"HI"<<endl;
sleep(1);
}
return 1;
}
` and run as like this `./a.out | gawk '{ print strftime("%T"), $0 }' > & 10.log` ... not working.. 10.log file is empty

Comment: @Nadaraj: the "problem" is almost certainly just flushing... your OS/shell is allowed to collect quite a lot of `gawk` output in memory before it chooses to flush it to logfile.  But, after a while - e.g. 4096 characters - it should write a block to the file, and the timestamps will reflect the time that `gawk` was able to read the lines - because your program uses `endl` that should be almost immediately after each line was written by the C++ program: you'll see that more easily if you make the program stop after say 15 iterations.  That's just the way it works.

Comment: @Nadaraj: it's possible to "encourage" a program to use line buffering by making it think it's running against an interactive [pseudo-]terminal: `script -q /dev/null program`, you could put that in front of `awk`, but the shell itself may still buffer the output before writing to the `>&`-redirected destination....

Answer (score 1):

You could write a sample shell script to wrap that program, like this

```
program | while read msg; do
    date
    echo $msg
done
```

and redirect the output from this script to your log file.

If you do not like the default output of `date`, you could change its ouput by add proper options, see its manual `date(1)` for further details.

Comment: `echo $(date "+%T") $msg` will get the timestamp and program output onto the same lines.  (This shell approach will be *way* slower than `awk` or a C++ solution).

Comment: @TonyD Acutally, its the second part of the expected output that confused me, so I just give hints to let the asker himself figure out how to print the timestamp he wants. By the way, the slowness of shell script may not be a problem in the asker's case :-)